# undefined reference to `KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, audio, mingw

I am porting some code from Visual Studio to Mingw . When attempting to build the code I got the following linker error

```
 undefined reference to `KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM'
```

This is the piece of code that is causing the problem

```
                WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE *pex = reinterpret_cast<WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE*>(new char[sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE)]);

                ZeroMemory( pex, sizeof(*pex));

                pex->Format.nChannels = channels;
                pex->Format.nSamplesPerSec = samplesPerSec;
                pex->Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = samplesPerSec * blockAlign;
                pex->Format.wBitsPerSample = bitsPerSample;
                pex->Format.nBlockAlign =blockAlign;

                pex->Format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE;
                pex->Format.cbSize = sizeof(*pex)-sizeof(pex->Format);

                pex->Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = bitsPerSample;

                pex->SubFormat = KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM; // <--- ERROR
```

It seems like I need to put in the name of library file to get rid of this linker error. Any suggestions on how I could resolve this ? I have already added dsound , winmm , ks , ksuser,ksguid and ole32 to the linker options but I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM is a function pointer.
If you are pretty sure you have included all the libraries needed, I suggest you to rearrange the linking order of the libraries. Because g++(not sure if mingw also does) would look through you linking files and get what it wants, and ignores the rest. sometimes, if the order is wrong, the libraries in the behind depending on the previous libraries, this could cause what you saw.

Answer (score 3):

you should link libksuser.a (ex: `-lksuser`) to get KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM .
there is very few document about symbol belongs which library so I wrote a little script to help search the lib you should link

```
#!/bin/sh

 for lib in `ls /mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/*.a`
 do
    echo "search in $lib"
    nm $lib | grep KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM
 done
```

feel free to change the library location and the symbol you want to search

Comment: NB if you are cross compiling you'll need to use the "right" nm like `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm` however for me a grep was enough, you found me the right lib for KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_BDA_MPEG2_TRANSPORT thank you!